# When using generics in Rust, "the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time"

Tags: rust

The following code will work and print `Foo("hello")`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Foo<'a> {
    fn from(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Foo(s)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: &str = "hello";
    let foo = Foo::from(s);
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

However, if I use generics, and change all `str` into `T`, it won't work:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T> From<&'a T> for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn from(s: &'a T) -> Self {
        Foo(s)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: &str = "hello";
    let foo = Foo::from(s);
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> a.rs:12:25
   |
2  | struct Foo<'a, T>(&'a T);
   | ------------------------- required by `Foo`
...
12 |     let foo = Foo::from(s);
   |                         ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
```

Isn't `&'a T` equivalent to `&'a str`? Why is the compiler seemingly using `str` instead of `&'a str`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type parameters are implicitly `Sized` in rust. You should add `?Sized` constraint explicitly.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a, T: ?Sized>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T: ?Sized> From<&'a T> for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn from(s: &'a T) -> Self {
        Foo(s)
    }
}
```